# Do the note positions on a U-bass correspond to a Bass guitar?

Tags: bass-guitar, ukulele

I can't find any images of the layout of notes on a U-bass fretboard. Would a fretted U-bass play the same as a bass guitar, but with a shorter scale?

As far as I've found, the 4 strings share the E-A-D-G tuning. Would getting a U-bass work like a little travel bass, or would I have to relearn finger positions, scales, etc..?

Comment: If it's tuned EADG low to high, and the frets are semitones, how could the rest of the fretboard *not* be like a regular bass? (but with the frets closer together, as you note). If the frets aren't semitones, that would be weird enough that I think you'd have heard about it. (PS I want one, want want)

Comment: Ed, you're assuming I have the same knowledge you do.

Comment: That's a fair point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the positions correspond. That doesn't necessarily mean that you won't have to reconsider physical finger positions a little, because the spacing between notes is so much tighter, and you'll actually have more notes within reach from a given hand position.

Comment: Great! Thanks, topo morto. That should be close enough for a little on the road practice.